# How to update an attribute after create or update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I’m new to rails and I’m trying to figure out the following.

I’ve got a class Order which has attributes name, status and radius. The possible status are [draft,  posted, taken]. The radius can change from 500 to 5k incrementing 500 each time a loop runs. I would like to know how can I make the radius to change depending on the status and the time that has pass.

If  @order.status = draft, then status = 500. 
If @order.status = posted, then the radius’ value will start with 500 but increment by 500 every 10 seconds until it gets to  40.
If @order.status = taken, then the radius’ value will be equal to whatever the radius is when the status changed to taken.
if order.status != taken after the 40 seconds, the @order.status = draft and @order.radius = 500

The following code runs well in ruby for visualization only, if you copied an run it on the teminal you will see it running well.

count = 1
initial_radius = 500

puts "Enter the status: "
status = gets
status = status.chomp

while status == 'posted' && count < 4  # this will be the one deciding (n) #times for 10k max radius of search otherwise get back to draft

```
puts ""
puts "Run #{count}"
radius = 500
puts "Radius = #{radius}"  
n = 1
  while status == 'posted' && n <10
    status = 'posted'
    puts " Status is now =  #{status.capitalize}! "        
    sleep(1)
    puts "n = #{n}"
    puts "Enter the status: "
    status = gets
    status = status.chomp
    n += 1
    start = Time.now
    puts "Radius = #{radius}" 
  end

  if status == 'posted'  
    count += 1
    radius *= count
    puts "New Radius = #{radius}" 
  elsif status == 'taken'
    radius *= count
    puts ""
    puts "Order has been Taken with radius #{radius}!!"
    puts ""
  end
  #radius = 500 This was removed as it didn't affect
```

end

if status == 'taken'
  puts ""
else
  puts ""
  puts "No company took the order"
  puts "Order has gone back to status Draft and its radius is #{initial_radius} "
  puts ""
end

But when I try the following to see how the server behaves and I create a new Order it hangs until it finishes processing any order that has been placed before. I know that it hangs because of the sleep method. The code below is done only to see how it will behave. It does update the radius after 15 seconds but no one would like to use an application that needs to wait until someone else finish their bit.

Order model

after_save :change_radius, on: [:create, :update]

def change_radius
  if self.status == 'posted'
    sleep 15
    update_column(:radius, 1000)
  elsif self.status == 'draft'
    update_column(:radius, 500)
  end
end

My question is. How can I make it to work so it will be possible for any other user to use the application (create an order) without any hanging until it finish dealing with another user’s order.  I think it may need use of Active jobs or something similar but unsure how to set it up if this is the case. I would appreciate any guidance on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

For a process that takes a long time to complete, consider putting it in a background process. I would check out using [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) with redis. It's a good option for background processing.